# Passing PSCredential as parameter to script

Tags: powershell

how can I call one script from another script and pass a PSCredential as a parameter?

The code I have is converting the PSCredential to a string with `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential` as the string value so it doesn't work:

Error:

```
 Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'cred'. Cannot convert the 
"System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential".
```

Code:

```
function getCurrentSequenceNumber([System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$cred)
{
    $scriptPath = 'D:\Ave\A\Scripts\UploadPasswordToStorageTable\ReadTableEntity\Read-TableEntity.ps1'
    $argumentList = "-SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -TableName $TableName -partitionKey $partitionKey -rowKey $rowKey -Key $Key -CredentialName $CredentialName -cred $cred"
    $currentSequenceNumber = Invoke-Expression "$scriptPath $argumentList"
    return $currentSequenceNumber
}

$cred = Get-Credential
$currentSequenceNumber = getCurrentSequenceNumber $cred
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked:

```
& D:\Ave\A\Scripts\UploadPasswordToStorageTable\ReadTableEntity\Read-TableEntity.ps1 -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -TableName $TableName -partitionKey $partitionKey -rowKey $rowKey -Key $Key -CredentialName $CredentialName -cred $cred
```

You can't use an object in double quotes because it will serialize it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke-Expression takes a string and runs it as a scriptblock so you're effectively turning the PSCredential object into a string and than invoking it as a PSCredential object.

Have you tried using `&`?

```
function getCurrentSequenceNumber([System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$cred)
{
$scriptPath = 'D:\Ave\A\Scripts\UploadPasswordToStorageTable\ReadTableEntity\Read-TableEntity.ps1'
$argumentList = "-SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -TableName $TableName -partitionKey $partitionKey -rowKey $rowKey -Key $Key -CredentialName $CredentialName -cred $cred"
$currentSequenceNumber = & $scriptPath $argumentList
return $currentSequenceNumber
}

$cred = Get-Credential

$currentSequenceNumber = getCurrentSequenceNumber $cred
```

Comment: I think because you are putting $cred inside quotation marks, it still turns it into a string.

Comment: Also that gave me this error: & : The term D:\Ave\A\Scripts\UploadPasswordToStorageTable\ReadTableEntity\Read-TableEntity.ps1 -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -TableName $TableName -partitionKey $partitionKey -rowKey $rowKey -Key $Key -CredentialName $CredentialName -cred $cred' is 
not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.